# jQuery : hide one column based on another column

Tags: jquery

I have a simple HTML table containing 3 columns as shown below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alpha</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Beta</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to hide the 3rd column's value if there is value in 2nd column.

For example in my table (*from the code snippet*), since both the rows have value in the "Contact" column I want the data from the "Country" column to be hidden.

Is it possible to do this in jQuery ?

Comment: You should handle it with server side data. Like you can add check at the time of displaying values If(!empty($2nd_col_variable)){ //show value } let this remain empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will help you on this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table tbody tr").each(function() {
        contact = $.trim($(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html());
        if (contact) {
            $(this).children('td:nth-child(3)').html('');
        }
    });
});
```

I have used the pseudo class nth-child, you can also give class name for the td and use it to capture the data inside the cells.

Check the working *snippet.*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table tbody tr").each(function() {
        contact = $.trim($(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html());
        if (contact) {
            $(this).children('td:nth-child(3)').html('');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alpha</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Beta</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Gamma</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>USA</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>

</body>
</html>
```